# Deserialization: how to get the name of a variable giving an error

Tags: .net, vb.net, debugging, deserialization, type-conversion

I am deserializing a large object.

```
Dim Obj As Object = Nothing

Using FileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(File, System.IO.FileMode.Open)

    Dim BinaryFormatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
    Try
        Obj = BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(FileStream)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Notify(vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Using
```

Since a changed the type of a variable from double to integer, I am now receiving an error when deserializing ("Object of type 'System.Double' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.").

Problem is that having many variables now I don't remember which one I changed, and there is no clue in the error message (please, spare me insults, I know I have been silly  :-) ).

How do I get having the debugger to remind me the name of the offending field so i can change it back to double or rename it?

(c# or vb.net hints would be both useful: not a language-specific question)

Comment: is there an `InnerException` in the `Exception`?

Comment: I receive the error window pointing to the line Obj = BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(FileStream) but with no more clues (only the message: Object of type 'System.Double' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.)

Comment: as far as I know, when you get this error, the object could not be created so those variables do not exist.  A partial object is not created, but you can sometimes set breaks or Try/Catch in prop setters to trace down the culprit

Comment: I just want to know the name of the variable which cannot be converted on deserialization. Only that: it should be not much to ask for :-) Wonder why the error does not tell ?

Comment: As per Sayse, can't you inspect the ex variable, it might have an inner exception property, that too might have an inner exception property... or Me.Notify(vbCrLf & ex.ToString()) will provide the full error details.

Comment: I just changed "as double" in "as integer" nothing more.

Comment: ex.tostring() just provides the same useless message. No detail on variable name

Comment: it **cant** tell you that `FooVar` is the problem because a) your `Obj` was not created when serialization failed b) `FooVar` is not a member of System.Object c) trying to drill into an object var which is Nothing to get the name would likely result in a new NullReference exception.  Are these just fields or properties it is serializing?

Comment: Is there a way maybe to make the deserialization 1 field at a time so I can know which one is the one i changed ?

Comment: If they were Properties, not just Fields, you can use the prop setters to (often) find out the culprit (see 3rd comment).  If they are fields, I have no idea how to trap it.

Comment: I don't think you can; not with a Binary object.  If it had been serialised to XML, it would be easier...

Comment: It should be something like Public MyRetardedVariable as integer  :-)

Comment: thats a Field. I think you are out of luck.

Comment: I am surprised this looks hard. Before asking I was worried I was asking something trivial.

Comment: You should go back to last weeks backup (assuming of course you have one...!!) and retrieve from there.  Or do a diff on your source to figure out which variable you changed.

Comment: yep, damn I tried, but it's too confusing. I can figure it out (large project)